# Trying to create a class to reduce duplicate code, but stuck on an issue of enumeration for lack of a better term

Tags: python

I'm trying to use classes to condense some repeating functions, I'm probably missing something key.  Using the adafruit motorkit library.  It has a class called MotorKit(), then Motorkit has a motor<1-4> methods(?) each with a settable attribute of throttle for each of the 4 motors a board can control, and every one of my motors is controlling gates and will work the same way.

so what i have now is this:

```
board1=MotorKit(address=0x60)
def openMotor1():        
    board1.motor1.throttle = 1 #open output gate at full speed
    time.sleep(.1)   
    board1.motor1.throttle = 0.1 #apply minimal voltage to keep output gate open and from bouncing  
def openMotor2():
    board1.motor2.throttle = 1
    time.sleep(.1)
    board1.motor2.throttle = 0.1
... 
<for 12 motors>
```

I have 3 boards at different addresses, 4 motors on each board.  So i have 12 of the exact same function.  Then i have another 12 functions to close the motors in a similar way.  The motors and addresses will be enumerated in a .config file ultimately, as the number of motors in use will change.

So i'm imaging I should be able to do this with a class so i'm not repeating the exact same code over and over again?  However every attempt at a class doesn't work. Here's the rough idea of what I'm trying to do, **i know this isn't proper syntaxed code**, i'm just trying to depict my thought process, since none of my code has worked.  The <>'s represent a variable i want inserted:

```
class MotorClass:
     def __ init __ (self, MotorNumber, addy):
        board<address> = MotorKit(address=addy)
        # example: board0x60=Motorkit(address=0x60)

    def open(self):
        board<address>.motor<MotorNumber>.throttle = 1
        #example: board0x60.motor1.throttle = 1
        time.sleep(.1)
        board<address>.motor<MotorNumber>.throttle = 0.1
```

which I would then call like this

```
#Motor<X>=MotorClass(<MotorNumber>,<BoardAddress>)
Motor5=MotorClass(1,0x61) #so Motor5 might be the motor #1 on board #2 @ bus address 0x61
Motor5.open #would then the openMotor1() function i defined above except applying to board2.
```

How can i do this? or something with a similar intent?

Comment: I think it would be easier to help if you gave us an example of the class you actually tried and what didn't work about it. I would think a class could work for what you want to do.

Comment: How is your `MotorClass` different from the one in `MotorKit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always just pass the appropriate motor as an argument to a single function:

```
def openMotor(m):
    m.throttle = 1
    time.sleep(.1)
    m.throttle = 0.1


openMotor(board1.motor1)
# etc
```

Comment: This seems to be the best option, was so simple i missed it.  Issue is i'm stuck using "eval" to get it to work

Comment: Why do you (think you) need `eval`?

Answer (score 0):

I think using a dictionary to keep all the motor instances would help:

```
class MotorClass:

    def __init__(self, board_address_list, number_of_motor_per_board):
        self.all_motor = {} # {(board_id, motor_id): motor instance}
        for i, a in enumerate(board_address_list):
            board = MotorKit(address=a)
            for x in range(1, 1+number_of_motor_per_board):
                self.all_motor[(i, x)] = getattr(board , 'motor' + str(x)) # equivalent to board.motorx
```

To open:

```
def open_motor(self, motor):
    motor.throttle = 1
    time.sleep(.1)
    motor.throttle = 0.1

def open_all(self):
    for m in self.all_motor.values():
        self.open_motor(m)

def open_one(self, board_id, motor_id):
    m = self.all_motor[(board_id, motor_id)]:
    self.open_motor(m)
```

In fact if you just want to start all motors given all the board addresses:

```
for a in addresses:
    board = MotorKit(address=a)
    for x in range(1, 1+number_of_motor_per_board):
        motor_start_function(getattr(board , 'motor' + str(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

One brute force way:

```
class MotorClass(MotorKit):
    def __init__(self, address):
        MotorKit.__init__(self,address)
        self.motors = [self.motor1,self.motor2,self.motor3,self.motor4]
    def throttle(self, idx, value):
        self.motors[idx].throttle = value
```

You might use set_throttle to avoid confusion.